# Any way to gray out the dates before startDate in bootsrap 4 date picker?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, datepicker

Just to be clear, I know how to set startDate. The problem for me is graying out the dates before startDate and also how to change the cursor on the datepicker to be pointer? I read that bootstrap is supposed to gray out the areas automatically but for me I can't just select the dates before startDate. Color is the same.
Things I have tried:

1. Tried bunch of css but wasn't able to gray out
2. NO bootstrap property exists to do that

I'd really appreciate any help. Below is the datepicker and the way I have set up the datepicker
HTML

```
<input id="start-date" data-provide="datepicker" onchange="dateChanged()" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

JS

```
$('#start-date').datepicker({
autoclose:true,
startDate: date,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Comment: This is default behaviour, and it works. You can test it yourself in the [sandbox](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=02-24-2020&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Comment: [`startDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) should be doing it so what is `date` if it is not working.

Comment: @epascarello startDate works by not allowing me to select date before startDate. However, it doesn't gray out the dates before startDate.

Comment: My guess is either you are not using correct date for start Date or you have some style in your CSS that is overriding the styles.

Comment: @epascarello That was my thought as well. I tried removing all the css as well. And the format for startDate is correct because as I mentioned in my post, the function isn't affected. User can't select the dates before startDate. Those dates aren't just grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Using startDate, the days are grayed out.

```js
$('#my-date').datepicker({
startDate: (new Date())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-date">
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check with this and let you know. Maybe it was because I was using 1.7.1 datepicker?